# error with free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, free, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working on a project involving interpolation, I've implemented my interpolating functions as classes, and when I try to run my piecewise interpolation algorithm I'm getting the following error message: `free(): invalid next size(fast)` with a memory address.

The relevant part of my main function is:

```
double * xx = new double [n];
xx[0] = a;
xx[n - 1] = b;
for (int i=1; i<n - 1; i++) xx[i] = (rand() % 1000) * (b - a) / 1000 + a;
PwLin pv1 (n, a, b, 1, xx, 1);
PwLin pv2 (n, a, b, 2, xx, 1);
PwLin pv3 (n, a, b, 3, xx, 1);
```

...

```
cin >> x;
cout << pv1.eval(x) << '\t' << abs(f1(x, 1) - pv1.eval(x)) << endl;
cout << pv2.eval(x) << '\t' << abs(f2(x, 1) - pv2.eval(x)) << endl;
cout << pv3.eval(x) << '\t' << abs(f3(x, 1) - pv3.eval(x)) << endl;
```

The PwLin class is

```
class PwLin
{
double * xl, * yl, * h;
double a, b;
int n;
bool uni;
public:
double eval(double);
PwLin(int, double, double, int, double);
PwLin(int, double, double, int, double *, double);
~PwLin(){};
};
```

and the eval() function is

```
double PwLin::eval(double x)
{
int i=0;
while (x > xl[i]) i++;
if (uni == 1){
return (yl[i - 1] * (xl[i] - x) + yl[i] * (x - xl[i - 1])) / h[0]; }
else return (yl[i - 1] * (xl[i] - x) + yl[i] * (x - xl[i])) / h[i];
}
```

I've searched a bit and found that the `free(): invalid next size` error is caused by a memory leak, but I have no idea where it is.  When I run the function the error doesn't occur until I enter an x value to test, so it seems to be an issue with the `eval()` function rather than the constructor, but I don't have any memory actions at all in `eval()` or in the while loop, I have no idea what the problem is.

and uh, I installed ubuntu last week and have no idea how to use it, I'm using gedit which afaik has no debugging utility and if there's anything fancier in ubuntu I don't know what it is

Comment: Run valgrind. It will show you WHERE you are doing something wrong, and it's almost certainly that you are overwriting the end of your allocation.

Comment: Replace the arrays with `std::vector` and your memory management issues will go away.

Comment: Note that it's not a memory leak, but mishandling of memory that is the problem here, and `std::vector` is not a certain cure for that.

Comment: How the class constructors are implemented?

Comment: Here `while (x > xl[i]) i++;` you never check if `i >= n`. Are you sure that doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

This may not fix any of your problems, but ...

These lines can easily lead to out of bounds access.

```
int i=0;
while (x > xl[i]) i++;
```

You should replace them with:

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; i < n; ++i )
{
   if ( x >= xl[i] )
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

Deal with the case when you have gone through all the items in `xl`.

```
if ( i == n )
{
   // can't interpolate. Do something about it.
}
```

Comment: thanks, took your advice, also found my problem, I'd made vector h size n-1 and tried to write its nth term.  sadly it seems my function is still completely broken as I've messed up the actual numerical programming.